# Get production APNS token

Tags: xcode, cordova, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

In development everything works fine:

- my app (built with Phonegap) sends the device token to the server
- my server sends the notification to the Apple servers
- I receive the notification on my iPhone

But, when I switched to production (enabled push notifications and created a new SSL certificate for production) I keep getting "(8) Invalid token" from [Rapns](https://github.com/ileitch/rapns) (which is installed on my push notification server).

I have read that this message is probably caused because I use a development device token in production (i.e. my server use a *production certificate*, but the app is running in development and sends a *development device token* to the server).

**How can I run the app in production mode, so that I get a valid device token for production**?

I think I should use an Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning profile, but even if I have changed the "Code Signing Identity" properly in Build settings, **I still get the same token I was getting in development**! And this obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Solved by creating an **archive** - instead of run - and signing it with an Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning profile.

Comment: You can accept your own answer so we know that this question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to delete the already installed application on the device - do a xcode clean up(for a safer side) - reinstall the application.